# Migrate from RACSignal to ReactiveSwift or RAC5

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive, racsignal, reactive-swift

I'm new with Swift, and that's why I'm new with Reactive Cocoa v5 or Reactive Swift.

Previously I used RACSignal with RAC 2.x and I liked to do something like this:

```
- (RACSignal *)signalForGET:(NSString *)URLString parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters {
  return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id <RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
      AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [self GET:URLString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
          [subscriber sendNext:responseObject];
          [subscriber sendCompleted];
      } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
          [subscriber sendError:error];
      }];
      return [RACDisposable disposableWithBlock:^{
          [op cancel];
      }];
   }];
}
```

And here I loved that it cancels request on disposable, and also I could cancel it manually by calling `dispose` method on the returned signal.

I'm a little bit confused about all this stuff in Reactive Swift, like SignalProducers etc.

Please give me example how to implement the same with newest Swift/ReactiveSwift/ReactiveCocoa versions. **Main requirement** is to have ability to cancel request (or dispose signal) wherever I want, and to have request automatically getting cancelled on dispose

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The important thing to understand about `Signal` and `SignalProducer` is the distinction between `Hot` and `Cold` Signals.

Basically, a `Hot` Signal is one that does not care about its Observers. It sends its values, no matter if it has one, multiple or even no observer at all. And most important: New observations do not cause side effects in the signal and each new subscriber will get the exact same events as the other subscribers (minus the ones that have already occurred before the subscription!)! Think things like user input, sensor data, ... (ignoring things like starting/stopping the sensor).

In my experience, real `Hot` Signals are rare in practice..

In contrast, a `Cold` Signal is one that cares about its Observers - each subscription to a `Cold` Signal potentially performs a side effect and the subscriber receives events based on that side effect. So two different observers each start the side effect once and get distinct sets of events.

In RAC, `Cold` Signals are represented by `SignalProducer`. You might also think of a `SignalProducer` as a Factory for Signals (hence the name) - `start`ing a `SignalProducer` performs the side effect and returns a `Signal` on which the events are sent.

Thats pretty much what your snippet does.

`Disposable` has not changed much since RAC 2.x, you can still use that. You probably have just missed how to use it when creating a `SignalProducer`:

```
func producerForGET(urlString: String, parameters: [String: String]) -> SignalProducer<Data, NSError> {
    return SignalProducer<Data, NSError> { observer, disposable in
        let operation = GET(url: urlString, parameters: parameters, success: { operation, responseObject in
            observer.send(value: responseObject)
            observer.sendCompleted()
        }, failure: { error in
            observer.send(error: error)
        })

        disposable += {
            print("Disposed")
            operation.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a quick example how to use this can be used:

```
producerForGET(urlString: "Bla", parameters: [:])
    .start()    // Performs the request and returns a Signal
    .dispose()  // Runs the disposable block and cancels the operation
```

Comment: Thanks bro. That's is mostly the same what I was trying before asking here, but was confused because Xcode autocomplete didn't recognize this kind of signal producer initializer. Also I didn't get why it doesn't allow to use Error type for errors here... But thank you very much.