# ReactiveCocoa 5, ReactiveSwift network sub-request handling & best practice

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa, racsignal, reactive-swift

I'm trying to find best practice to handle multiple **sub-requests** per each value got from parent request. I'm trying to use the same logic as here - [Reactive Cocoa 5 and ReactiveSwift network requests handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43490471/reactive-cocoa-5-and-reactiveswift-network-requests-handling), but have some problems.

**What we have and need:**
*1. TableView with infinite scrolling handler (SVPullToRefresh)*
*2. Fetch list of objects each time handler is called*
*3. Send "sub-request" for each object from response*

**Notes:**
1. All requests (parent + sub-requests) should become cancelled once viewController is closed (deinit called)
2. I need to have an ability to cancel parent request at any time. This should also cancel all sub-requests.

**What I currently have**

I know what I do in "infinite handler" is kinda "duct tape", but I'm new with ReactiveSwift...

```
self.tableView.addInfiniteScrollingWithActionHandler { [unowned self] in
    self.tempMutableProperty.value = true
}

self.tempMutableProperty.producer.skipNil().flatMap(.latest) { [unowned self] tempValueThatIDontNeed in
    return self.producerForParentRequest(offset: self.offset)
        .take(during: self.reactive.lifetime)
        .on(
            // handlers for errors, completed, etc
            value: { [unowned self] items in
                self.items.append(items)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.offset += items.count
                // SEND REQUEST #2 FOR EACH ITEM
            }
    ).flatMapError { error in
        return SignalProducer.empty
    }
}.observe(on: UIScheduler().start()
```

So, as you see, I have pagination with tableView. I'm fetching list of objects for each page. Then for each item from response I need to fetch an additional information with request #2.

---

**Flow and problems:**
**1.** Of course I want to get rid of `tempMutableProperty` and somehow start new `parent request` without some kinda of proxy
**2.** Each `sub-request` should be independent, which means I want to have `value/error` handler called for each `sub-request` separately, and NOT like it waits for all 10 sub-requests and then call success handler with all 10 responses collected. Also, fail on some specific sub-request should not affect on other sub-requests running
**3.** User can change his search request without waiting for whole request process beeing completed. This mean that once user changes some parameters, I will clear all items, and I need to cancel `parent request` within all `sub-requests` and start this all again.
**4.** In addition to #2, sometimes user can scroll down to fetch new portion of items. This will mean that new `parent request` should start, but `sub-requests` from previous response of `parent request` should continue working
**5.** All requests should become cancelled on `self.deinit`, so this all should work only during `self.lifetime`, but I'm not sure what is the correct place to put this parameter

I'm not sure if this all is possible without storing disposable/signals as properties of self, so that's not a problem if `sub-request` will be somehow stored as properties.

---

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

So, I will post here solutions for my problems.

**For point #1** I've made this:

```
let disposable = SerialDisposable()

self.tableView.addInfiniteScrolling(actionHandler: { [unowned self] in
    self.disposable.inner = nil // this is needed to force dispose current request before starting new one
    self.disposable.inner = self.producer().take(during: self.reactive.lifetime)
        .on(value: { [unowned self] value in
            // handle as you want
        }).start()
})
```

This helped me to get rid of `tempMutableProperty`. Instead of `flatMap` the `SerialDisposable` is used. 
So, this works fine for me, and it disposed request automatically when `self` is getting destroyed

**For other points** I've made this:

The idea was that I'm loading some items for table, then I need to send additional request per item to fetch detailed information for it. So, I created class, having 3 properties - `item`, `itemDetail`, `requestSent`.

Then in `willDisplay cell` I have

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if !self.items[indexPath.row].requestSent {
        self.items[indexPath.row].details <~ self.detailedProducerForItemID(self.items[indexPath.row].item.id)
        self.items[indexPath.row].requestSent = true
    }
}
```

**Note**: `self.items[indexPath.row].details` is a `MutableProperty<Details?>`

In the cell itself for representing details I have something like:

`let (detailsSignal, detailsObserver) = Signal<MutableProperty<Details?>, NoError>.pipe()`, where `Details` is the name of class for item's details.

In cell's `awakeFromNib`:

```
let details = self.detailsSignal.flatMap(.latest) { $0.producer }

self.detailsLabel.reactive.text <~ details.map { value -> String? in
    // handling `Details`
}
```

And in `cellForRow` I call `cell.detailsObserver.send(value: self.items[indexPath.row].details)`

And, when VC's `deinit` is called, or I perform a new `main` request, all requests are automatically getting cancelled, since when I use `self.items.removeAll()` it dispose all requests.

This is rough flow. If someone is interested in more details, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

For part 1, I would add an extension that turns the infinite scrolling action handling into a Signal:

```
extension Reactive where Base: UITableView {
    public func infiniteScrollingSignal() -> Signal<Void, NoError>
    {
        return Signal { [unowned base = self.base] observer in
            base.addInfiniteScrollingWithActionHandler  {
                observer.send(value: ())
            }

            return ActionDisposable {
                // Unsubscribe the infinite scrolling action handler here if necessary
            }
        }
        .take(during: self.lifetime)
    }
}
```

Then you can hook up all of your logic to `self.tableView.reactive.infiniteScrollingSignal()`

Comment: hmm... This is a little bit better than my solution since I don't need any kind of disposable properties stored. But it has just a "cosmetic issue" like it still sends dummy boolean value `true`, just to have `flatMap` closure called then. Anyway, that a good proposal, that will make viewController's code clearer

Comment: I think you can change the type from `Signal<Bool, NoError>` to `Signal<Void, NoError>`, and then send an empty tuple value: `observer.send(value: ())`. I wasn't sure off the top of my head, so I just used Bool.

Comment: Also, the Swift way of handling parameters you don't care about is to just use an underscore, like `flatMap(.latest) { _ in ... }`